# Format sectionNameKeyPath NSFetchedResultsController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am attempting to format my `sectionNameKeyPath` for my core data fetch using a stored `NSDate` attribute. It is fully working and pulling/sorting the records into sections based on the `NSDate` but I am not sure how to format it to display it by dd-mm-yyyy.

I know how to format `NSDate` using:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:myTimeInterval)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

My current fetch request using core data attribute `sectionDate` as the section division for `sectionNameKeyPath`

**FETCH**

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "VisitDetails")
let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateDue", ascending: false)
let sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "dateSections",
            cacheName: nil)
        
frc.delegate = self
```

So to clarify I am wanting to format the output and sort by just the dd-MM-yyy. Currently, it is looking like:

[image]

I presume a *Hack* is creating an additional attribute and inputting a formatted string then using this to section the results?

Comment: Two questions: 1. How is `dateSections` defined/calculated?  2. Do you really want to sort the sections by that format string?  Or do you want the sections sorted in date order, but formatted using that format string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did just this for a project that I'm working on.  Here's what I did:

Optional, but highly recommended, is to set up mogenerator.  There is a nice tutorial [here](http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/) for setting up your core data project to use it.

Regardless, in your data model, make sure you have a NSManagedObject subclass associated with the entity.  If you haven't already, and you're not using mogenerator, then you can [do it the apple way](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_mo_class.html).

In your VisitDetails class, add:

```
var formattedDateDue: String {
    get {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        // Apple suggested locale-aware technique:
        // dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        // dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        // ..or to stick to your original question:
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.dateDue)
    }
}
```

(Assuming you want your sections to be grouped on dateDue's date, otherwise make the computed attribute for your dateSections attribute.)  You then modify your fetched results controller from above to use the computed attribute:

```
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "formattedDateDue",
        cacheName: nil)
```

And that's all there is to it!

Comment: Hi @chris-eveland, I followed your code and it worked great on iOS10. On iOS11, the property is not recognised. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610890/core-data-ios11-nsunknownkeyexception-crash-in-sectionnamekeypath-with-custom