# sectionNameKeyPath NSFetchedResultsController gets ignored - Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I followed this suggestion:
[Format sectionNameKeyPath NSFetchedResultsController - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317346/format-sectionnamekeypath-nsfetchedresultscontroller-swift/44509106#44509106)

I'm having a bit of a problem with this implementation.
Using Xcode 8 and iOS 10.

I set Codegen to Manual/None and added my NSManagedObject Subclasses.

Then I added as you suggested:

```
var sectionIdentifier: String
{
    get
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        // dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        // dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        // ..or to stick to your original question:
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date! as Date)
    }
}
```

But for whatever reason it gets ignored by sectionNameKeyPath. When I enter "date" in sectionNameKeyPath I get the same result as AllReadyHome mentioned above.

I even tried:

```
return (date?.description)!
```

It didn't yield any results.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction...

**Update 1:**
That's what my fetchedResultsController look like:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Time> = Time.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: "Time")
```

Result: No sections
[image: No Sections]

When using date, which is an attribute of my entity:

```
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "date", cacheName: "Time")
```

It looks like this:
[image: Sections]

**Update 2:**
When using the sortDescriptor as suggested, I get a crash ("sectionIdentifier not in entity):

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Time> = Time.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionIdentifier", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: "Time")
```

**Update 3:**
I get the following warning when getting to the screen:

```
A section returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Objects will be placed in unnamed section
 CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController). A section returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Objects will be placed in unnamed section
```

Comment: use "sectionIdentifier" for the `sectionNameKeyPath`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, but I did. That's what does not work.

Comment: What exactly happens?  is the fetchedResultsController returning sectioned results? how are you setting up the header for the view?

Comment: How does your `NSFetchedResultsController` look? To be able to use `sectionNameKeyPath`, you need the same property as the first sort-descriptor

Comment: Thanks for your help! ;-) please see updates above

Comment: Additionally, when checking 'Transient' in my data model, I get a crash, although I should check it, right?

Answer (score 4):

use @objc for your sectionIdentifier

Sample:

```
@objc var sectionIdentifier: String {
    get {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: You save my day!