# Core Data iOS11 - NSUnknownKeyException crash in sectionNameKeyPath with custom property

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, ios11

I am using a `NSFetchedResultsController` in my app with a custom `sectionNameKeyPath` (named "`formattedDate`") to group together multiple elements in the table view.

The `formattedDate` property is a property defined in an extension of my NSManagedObject (I am using Xcode automatic codeine for Class definition, this is the reason why I added this property in the extension). This property is not in the Core Data model (not a transient property).

```
extension ActivityMO {
    var formattedDate: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: endDate as Date!)
    }
}
```

My app is running fine on iOS10.

On iOS11, I get the following error and the app crashed:

`2017-08-10 11:52:12.735277+0200 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< ActivityMO 0x60000048f820> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity ActivityMO is not key value coding-compliant for the key "formattedDate".'`

What am I doing wrong? Has something changed with iOS11?

Thanks,

Axel

Comment: Please use Xcode 9 to code for iOS 11.

Comment: @Lumialxk of course I am using Xcode 9 (Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q)).

Comment: Try `@objc var formattedDate: String {...}`